# How to configure Declarative Link Binding in jersey 2.22.1 in web.xml?

Tags: jersey

How to configure Declarative Binding in jersey 2.22.1 in web.xml, without using the Application base class and registering it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

You can declare an `<init-param>` to register specific (comma separated) resources/provider/features. For example

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.classnames</param-name>
    <param-value>
        org.foo.myresources.MyDogResource,
        org.glassfish.jersey.linking.DeclarativeLinkingFeature
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Also one thing to note, is that pretty much anything you can configure in the `ResourceConfig`, you can also configure in a [`Feature`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Feature.html). For example

```
@Provider
public class MyFeature implements Feature {
    @Override
    public boolean configure(FeatureContext context) {
        context.register(DeclarativeLinkingFeature.class);
    }
}
```

This way the `@Provider` is scanned for when you are package scanning, and will register the feature.